# How can I create a waitlist when a Google Form submission limit is reached?

Tags: google-apps-script, registration

What is the best way to limit the number of people who can submit a Google Form, then offer others the option of joining a waiting list once the limit is reached?

I can use the following script to close the form when a defined limit is reached, but would like instead to open a different form at that point to collect waitlist submissions.

```
function closeForm() {
    // get active form
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

    // retrieve number of responses thusfar
    var responses = form.getResponses();

    // set close message
    var msg = "We're sorry, but this session is full. Future sessions will be announced in the CISL Daily Bulletin. Thank you for your interest.";

    // do the math
    if(responses.length >= 1) {
        form.setAcceptingResponses(false).setCustomClosedFormMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

I've checked the Google Docs Help Forum and searched here. What little I have found so far is based on an older version of Google Forms.

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the very best approach to do that but I thought about a solution that works as expected but **- and this is a serious warning -** is a bit *tortuous*...

Anyway, if your form is not too complex it might be quite easy to setup.  The example below works with a form that has only text fields so the code is very simple. If you use different question types you'll have to add a condition for every type you use and adapt the addElement consequently.

The global idea is to make a backup form to hold all the existing fields, delete all the fiels and create a single '*give your name*' field for the waiting list.

Then a `restore` function allows for re-building the form without pain.

The form public url will always be the same and the form can be reused indefinitely... That's the main (only) advantage of this script.

Maybe someone will suggest a smarter and/or simpler solution, I'd be happy to learn from it.

**EDIT :** I added a onFormSubmit trigger creation function and changed a bit the logic to best suit the normal workflow : while the number of responses is < limit, the script returns without any effect. When limit is reached, the form is modified automatically.

```
function createTrigger(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkFormForLimit').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function checkFormForLimit() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  Logger.log(responses.length);
  if(responses.length<5) {return};// do nothing if not over the limit
  if(DriveApp.getFilesByName('backup'+form.getTitle()).hasNext()){ // check if bkp already exists
    var formBkp = FormApp.openById(DriveApp.getFilesByName('backup'+form.getTitle()).next().getId());// if it does, open it
  }else{
    var formBkp = FormApp.create('backup'+form.getTitle());// else create it
  }
  var msg = "We're sorry, but this session is full. Future sessions will be announced in the CISL Daily Bulletin. Thank you for your interest.";
  formBkp.setDescription(form.getDescription());
  form.setDescription(msg);
  var items = form.getItems();
  for(var n in items){
    var item = items[n];
    if(item.getType()==FormApp.ItemType.TEXT){
      formBkp.addTextItem().setTitle(item.getTitle());
      form.deleteItem(item);
    }
  }
  form.addTextItem().setTitle('Type your name to subscribe to the wait list')
}

function restoreForm(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.deleteItem(form.getItems()[0]);
  var formBkp = FormApp.openById(DriveApp.getFilesByName('backup'+form.getTitle()).next().getId());
  form.setDescription(formBkp.getDescription());
  var items = formBkp.getItems();
  for(var n in items){
    var item = items[n];
    if(item.getType()==FormApp.ItemType.TEXT){
      form.addTextItem().setTitle(item.getTitle());
      formBkp.deleteItem(item);
    }
  }
}
```